# Npm installs global (my) module with incorrect run command

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm creating a module that I want to be installed globally, package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-module",
  "description": "My module",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "..."
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "..."
  },
  "files": [
    "lib",
    "public",
    "README.md",
    "index.js",
    "my-module.js",
    "package.json",
    "tests"
  ],
  "engines": [
    "node >= 0.10.0"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
   ....     
  },
  "scripts": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "bin": {
    "module": "./module.js"
  }
}
```

So I published it to npm registry, after installation (on Windows):
I have incorrect files in global npm modules:

```
my-module:
"$basedir/node_modules/my-module/my-module.js"   "$@"
exit $?

my-module cmd:
"%~dp0\node_modules\my-module\my-module.js"   %*
```

While other installed global packages have more code in their cmd files.

Maybe something wrong with my package json? But I've looked at other module's package.json files and cannot get what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, bin module (my-module.js) should contain comment in first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```